# running limited number of process through Django

Tags: linux, django, android-asynctask

My Django project runs a system command on user image data. The system command takes long time and resources and I want to limit number of task running on the system. For example if user 'A' and 'B' submits a task both can run but if another user submits job the job while 2 jobs are already running, it has to wait till one of the job finish. So at a time only 2 task will be running. Any easy solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for Queue with `maxsize` set to a positive value (and potentially with `timeout`):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Note that it is thread safe.